# ASP MVC multi-view form models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, models

I am pretty new to this stuff but I am running into a concept-wall and I keep going back and forth with the best way to handle the problem.

I have a multi-view process to filling out a "New User Form". Each view has a small part of the entire form. In each view I have a model and the model has properties set to an instance of a LINQ to SQL class (for pre-populating) along with dropdown data (state, country). I also thought I should have a model (value object) that represents the entire form. This value object has properties for each LINQ class as well. So I made the view take the value object as a dependency injection. Then what? Just set a property to ViewData to send in multiple models? Seems like a bad idea since I would have to do that to every view. Should all view models come from a base class with the value object?

I might be way off already. Hopefully someone can help me get back on track. The ultimate goal is to have an object that represents the state/data of a form that spans multiple views and the form fields should populate if data is present.

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I am going to try to answer my own question but I am still not sure about things. I am going to use the info I got here: http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc/tutorial-13-cs.aspx to create an instance of the value object that will be available to every view. Then I am sending the instance (or a property of) into the view model through it's constructor.

I am still working on how to keep the instance of the value object through all pages but I am assuming it will have to be done through a session variable of sorts.